# how to use savetocassandra when table has more than 22 fields?

Tags: scala, cassandra

Here is some usefull link: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/a4JND9jiNCY

How to use the reference code in above google discussion?
I'm not able to understand the scala code please explain it with some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can create a tuple and then call SaveToCassandra on it.  Something like this:

```
val myRdd = sc.cassandraTable("mykeypace", "mytable")
val myTransformedRdd = myRdd.map {
  ( myRdd.getString("field1"), myRdd.GetString("field3") )
}
myTransformedRdd.saveToCassandra("mykeyspace", "someothertable", SomeColumns("field1", field3"))
```

The type of myRdd is RDD[CassandraRow].  The type of myTransformedRdd is RDD[(string, string)].

Under the hood, Scala is actually using a Tuple2[string, string].  Scala supports all the way to Tuple22.  Newer versions of Scala support more.

In cases where you have a structure that has more than 22 fields, you can construct an RDD of some other type.  For instance, you can construct an RDD[CassandraRow].

If I took the code above and changed it to use CassandraRow objects instead of tuples, it might look like this:

```
val myRdd = sc.cassandraTable("mykeypace", "mytable")

//build an array of the column names which we need later to make a CassandraRow object
val allColumnNames = Array[String](
  "field1",
  "field2"
)

//loop through the column names and create ColumnName objects from them
//we will need this later when we call SomeColumns()
val columnRefs = for(item <- allColumnNames) yield {
  new ColumnName(item)
}

val myTransformedRdd = myRdd.map {

  //create an Indexed Sequence with all of the values
  //we will need this to create the CassandraRow object
  val allValues = IndexedSeq[AnyRef](myRdd.GetString("field1"), myRdd.GetString("field3"))


  new CassandraRow(allColumnNames, allValues)
}

//the _* syntax tells Scala to take our columnRefs array and pass them into SomeColumns in the correct way
myTransformedRdd.saveToCassandra("mykeyspace", "someothertable", SomeColumns(columnRefs:_*)
```

These two pieces of code accomplish the same thing, but the second version lets you pass in more than 22 items in you structure